# PHP Large Float, need to round

Tags: php, floating-point, rounding

I have a program that is giving me this number: 9.1466606511048E-8
I need to round that, using most obvious functions in PHP gives me 0.

Comment: Well, 9.1466606511048E-8 is *pretty darn close to 0* (it is 0.000000091466... 9.1E8 is a much different number)

Comment: What about the 0 result is bothering you?

Comment: This question is vague.  Why is 0 unacceptable?  What do you need to round it to?  How are you trying to round it currently?

Comment: This question makes no sense. round($num,7) is the only thing that I think could work, and that would give you 1E-7 most likely, there is nothing else you can round to, because from there it all rounds to zero

Comment: yeah thanks I realized my noob answers shortly after this post, idiot ftw

Answer (score 4):

That's because that number has a value of 0.000000091466606511048, which is very close to zero. Perhaps you need to be more specific about what sort of rounding you want.

Answer (score 0):

How many decimals are you attempting to round to?

The number that you specified is the same as: 0.000000091466606511048

If you're using the round function without specifying to what decimal place you want to round, then it is going to round to zero because of the value.